# Convert 2D binary matrix to black/white image in java

Tags: java, image, matrix, binary

I am new for java. I have 2D binary matrix with only 1s and 0s now. I want to save it as jpg image(black and white) with same width and height. How could I realize that? I tried the code below but failed, saying  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!" Please help me with that or give me your better solution. Thank you very much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //result is double[25][33] binary matrix with only 1s and 0s;
    int height=result.length;
    int width=result[0].length;;
    byte[] data = new byte[height*width];
    int k=0;
    for(int i = 0;i < height;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            data[k]=(byte)result[i][j];
            k++;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage output = ImageIO.read(input);
    ImageIO.write(ouput, "jpg", new File("c:/result.jpg"));

}
```

Comment: *"How could I realize that?"*  I suspect one way is to draw each pixel to a [`BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_BINARY) and save that.  But not as a JPG, which does not accurately preserve colors.  For anything more than suspicions, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (it would only take some imports, and wrapping that in a `class`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example that creates a 30x30 checkered box:

[image]

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int w = 30, h = 30;

    // create the binary mapping
    byte BLACK = (byte)0, WHITE = (byte)255;
    byte[] map = {BLACK, WHITE};
    IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(1, map.length, map, map, map);

    // create checkered data
    int[] data = new int[w*h];
    for(int i=0; i<w; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<h; j++)
            data[i*h + j] = i%4<2 && j%4<2 || i%4>=2 && j%4>=2 ? BLACK:WHITE;

    // create image from color model and data
    WritableRaster raster = icm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icm, raster, false, null);

    // output to a file
    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

For what you are doing you actually don't need to create your own ImageColorModel, you can use a built in type: BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY or TYPE_BYTE_BINARY. Here is a better example and shows how to use grayscale to get a checkered box:

[image]

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    int w = 40, h = 40, divs = 5;

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    WritableRaster raster = bi.getRaster();

    for(int i=0; i<w; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<h; j++)
            raster.setSample(i,j,0,128+(int)(127*Math.sin(Math.PI*i/w*divs)*Math.sin(Math.PI*j/h*divs)));

    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but what if I want to output matrix into image range from 0 to 255? Is that right to write like this: byte[] map = new byte[256];
for(int i=0;i<256;i++){map[i]=(byte)i;}
IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(8, map.length, map, map, map);

Answer (score 1):

`JHeatChart` does this job as well without you having to create a custom image library.

http://www.javaheatmap.com/

```
// Create some dummy data.
double[][] data = new double[][]{{3,2,3,4,5,6},
                                 {2,3,4,5,6,7},
                                 {3,4,5,6,7,6},
                                 {4,5,6,7,6,5}};

// Step 1: Create our heat map chart using our data.
HeatChart map = new HeatChart(data);

// Step 2: Customise the chart.
map.setTitle("This is my heat chart title");
map.setXAxisLabel("X Axis");
map.setYAxisLabel("Y Axis");

// Step 3: Output the chart to a file.
map.saveToFile(new File("java-heat-chart.png"));
```

What you are essentially trying to do is make a heat map. And instead of a range of values ranging from 0 to whatever, you have a range of 0 and 1.

Replace `double[][] data = new double[][](//etc);` with your boolean array.