# Visualisation of boolean data

Tags: visualization

I am working on a surface simulation where the surface is divided into nxn blocks. I try and fill up the surface with a set of rules. After the simulation I get a 2-D boolean array output for example if n=10, I get

```
0011111110
0001101111
1011111111
0101100110
0011111100
0011100000
1111100000
0011110010
0000110000
0000110000
```

I would like to visualise this data in the form of a square image where all positions with zero are of one color and all positions with 1 are of another color. I have the boolean data output to a .txt file in the format of 1's and 0's as shown above. Is there some class in java I can use for this visualisation? I only understand the basics, so it shouldn't be too tough to implement. Also, if there's another Language/Programme that can make this process easier please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/20321606/395718

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica can do it easily

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Python and numpy/matplotlib libraries for basic "HeatMap".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(101)
g = np.floor(np.random.random((100, 100)) + .5)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.imshow(g)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.imshow(g, cmap='Greys',  interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig('blkwht.png')

plt.show()
```

If you want to use Java:

1. convert your Boolean[][] array to a Byte[][]  array
2. use this Byte[][] array as an InputStream for your image

   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));