# How to convert a matrix to an image in java

Tags: java, image, matrix

I have a matrix a[512][512] filled with 1 and 0, how could I convert this matrix to an image(.png,.jpg,etc).

Comment: Interesting question. What you figured so far how you could actually do it? I mean - besides asking other people to do your work?

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment, but from google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321606/convert-2d-binary-matrix-to-black-white-image-in-java

Comment: [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) takes some effort to set up for java I guess, never done it.

Answer (score 4):

This will create a grayscale image from the matrix you created:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//Consider class and methods predefined. The following will be within a method

try {
    BufferedImage image;
    for(int i=0; i<yourmatrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<yourmatrix[].length; j++) {
            int a = yourmatrix[i][j];
            Color newColor = new Color(a,a,a);
            image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
    File output = new File("GrayScale.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
}

catch(Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach where you could avoid the for loop if you started with a 1D big array for the whole image.

```
int width = 512;
int height = 512;
byte[][] a = new byte[width][height];

byte raw[] = new byte[width * height];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, raw, i*width, width);
}
//Arrays.fill(raw, width*height/2, width*height, (byte)1);
byte levels[] = new byte[]{0, -1};
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, 
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED,
        new IndexColorModel(8, 2, levels, levels, levels));
DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(raw, raw.length);
SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 1, width * 1, new int[]{0});
Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
image.setData(raster);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
```